# Azure Webjob suddenly stops working

Tags: php, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure Webjob (PHP Script) which runs every hour to import 100k data rows into a data table (basically 1000 inserts without transactions).
However the Azure Webjob just stops randomly after some inserts (sometimes 3k, sometimes 30k) and I don't know why. I checked the job logfile and php error logs but nothing is there. It looks like the php.exe from webjub suddenly gets killed.

Does someone know what can cause this behavior or what I can try ?

Thanks!

Comment: you can try posting your code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. We had a composer package called jobby which is a CRON replacement and it somehows not work correctly in our environment. Without it and just the Webjob it is working fine.